# Is Sentora (the web hosting control panel) dead?

Tags: vps, control-panel

I cannot open its website(sentora.org), nor can I install it on my VPS. Is this project dead, or just a temporary issue? It is a pity if the project is closed forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find nothing conclusive but **I see no evidence the project is closed**. Its not very active though.   After looking at whois and traceroute my guess is there is a network/isp issue. This is bolstered by the fact that there is no "file not found" or "domain for sale" or other message showing intent - just a failure of the isp servers to respond.

The project us still available on Github though - https://github.com/sentora/

(Also, the domain name is still registered an pointed, and there is no "good bye message" associated with it that I can see).

Update:

The Sensora.org site is now partially back with an explanatory message:

```
  Sorry for the inconvenience but our main server that is hosted at OVH hosting in Strasbourg, france.

  Had a major fire at it's datacenter :-(.

  Sentora's current main server data was stored there and maybe lost.

  Please stand by while we set up a temp solution.

  We are hoping to recover all data/systems when OVH restores all systems and servicies. (1-2 weeks) Hopefully.

  Thank you for your support as we restore service and installs.



  Sentora 2.0 BETA is going to be released soon. Stay tuned.
```

Comment: @william I updated my answer - sensora was affected by the ovh dc outage.